# Cannot Initialize Python After Unexpected System Reboot

Tags: python, python-2.7

`Python 2.7.3` on Windows 7 64bit.

So basically after an unexpected power failure, now I cannot even start python in command line, and the problem is rather weird:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site.py", line 552, in main
    aliasmbcs()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\site.py", line 477, in aliasmbcs
    import locale, codecs
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\locale.py", line 15, in <module>
    import encodings
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.3\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    _aliases = aliases.aliases
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'aliases'
```

Obviously `aliases` dictionary is right inside `aliases.py`, so what went wrong?

Comment: Interpreter files are corrupted, just reinstall it.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski You mean reinstall whole `Python 2.7`? Is it safe to reinstall/overwrite to the same place and still keep all my already-installed 3rd party packages? Is there a way to find out which file is corrupted and replace that file?

Comment: I'd start with just reinstalling the `aliases` module. If that doesn't work, then the whole Python interpreter. Most third party modules should still be there afterwards (if you don't delete the directory Python was installed in the first time). Also, on Windows at least, the installer may have an option to"repair" the existing installation. Note that if you had proper backups, you would be in this situation...

Comment: Just tried with Repair, but it didn't work. So I removed it and then installed again, now everything works all right. Imported several 3rd party modules, looks like they're all fine. Hopefully there won't be any problems. Cheers